# Openoffice Calc (or Excel) count matches in other cell in column

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I've searched to no avail, and my spreadsheet skills are simply not sufficient to tackle this.

Say I have 5 rows of numbers in 90 columns. For each column I want to find the maximum number. That is easy enough, and I can create an auxiliary row for this. However, what I want is to count how many columns each row contains the maximum number for.

In a dataset like the following:

```
a b c d 
1 2 3 4 
5 4 3 2 
4 4 4 4 
1 1 1 1
```

I want the following:

```
 a b c d   countmax
 1 2 3 4   1
 5 4 3 2   2
 4 4 4 4   3
 1 1 1 1   0
```

With the auxiliary row would, it would look like this:

```
 a b c d   countmax
 1 2 3 4   1
 5 4 3 2   2
 4 4 4 4   3
 1 1 1 1   0
 5 4 4 4
```

I've looked into `sumproduct`, `countif`, `hlookup`, `vlookup`, and others, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I have currently worked around it by adding an extra row for each row, and doing a comparison on each cell, then counting the boolean results. ( cell content: "*=IF(a1 = a5;1;0)*" content in the cell for the final column: "*=COUNTIF(a6:d6;1)*" )

Ideally, the solution is a formula that does not depend on any auxiliary cells, and just goes column by column, counting how many times the cell in that row and column is maximum value. I would also be curious to know how to do it with the single auxiliary row, since the approach would require a cell comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> "I would also be curious to know how to do it with the *single* auxiliary row."

With the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:D1=$A$5:$D$5))
```

[image]

Comment: Seeing as Tom Sharpe's answer doesn't work for OpenOffice, how could I convert this into an answer /without/ the need for the auxiliary row?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do it in Open Office without the auxiliary row.

Comment: @insaner you could do it without the auxiliary row with a formula like `=(A1=MAX($A$1:$A$4))+(B1=MAX($B$1:$B$4))+(C1=MAX($C$1:$C$4))+(D1=MAX($D$1:$D$4))`,  just for 90 columns :)

Comment: You mean type that out for the 90 columns? heh.. that would not be worth the trouble.

Comment: hehe I agree, it just occurred to me that that's "technically" a way to do it without the auxiliary row... :)

Comment: Could I use "address()" to do that for me?

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how you'd want to use it? What exactly are you trying?

Comment: Some calculation that takes each column, does a `max` or `rank` using the 5 rows as specified by `address` somehow. So, it takes the base row and column address say: "b1" and turns it into 5 values: "b1, b2, b3, b4, b5".. I just have so little understanding of how it all works together, I don't know how to express what I am thinking could be a solution to this.

Comment: My gut feeling is that using `address` won't be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

To do it without an auxiliary row, you can use Offset to get each column in turn, then Subtotal to get the maximum of each column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:D1=SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($A$1,0,COLUMN($A$1:$D$4)-COLUMN($A$1),ROWS($A$1:$D$4)))))
```

This should be fine normally, but Offset is a volatile function and may cause performance issues with large sheets. Also, this combination of Offset and Subtotal is peculiar to Excel and doesn't work in Open Office or Google Sheets.

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, unfortunately, as you mention, this doesn't work for openoffice Calc, which is what I need the solution for.

Comment: It does give me a parting point to try to figure this out for OpenOffice